# texture nodes: question of alpha!

Tags: materials, node-editor, shaders

I added this fence texture to these poles.
(link:https://ambientcg.com/view?id=Fence007A

They look alright in separate views of the poles,
but with all the environments and everything apparently I don't know what goes wrong with the left one.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your blender file or outliner screenshots to know what's there, but it looks like you have some object behind the pole. Delete or move it and it will be fixed.

Comment: thank you it's fixed and idk why...it just disappeared......

Comment: @coffeeblood You mean that it fixed automatically? I think you might have some material preview thing or something going on, at least you're back in business :)